# Will code created with 32 Bit SharePoint Designer 2013 be readable to another computer with the 64 Bit version of SPD 2013?

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, 2013, error

One of the developers on my team is installing SharePoint Designer 2013 on a machine with 32 Bit office.  He attempted to install the 64 bit version and this error appeared:
Got we can't install the 64-bit version of office because we found the following 32-bit Programs on your PC:  Visio 2010 and Office Pro Plus 2010.

He is going to install the 32 bit version of sharepoint designer 2013 but we are wondering if that poses any risks regarding the code.

Is the only difference in 32 vs 64 bit that it takes longer to debug?

Would hate to create a bunch of code at home on 32 bit version and get to the office and have the 64 bit verion not be able to read or execute (wha wha wha) or create a bunch of code at the office that the 32 bit version would not be able to read.

Are there any other differences?

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue in using 32 bit SPD on some machines and 64 bit on others. But my general recommendation would be to always use 32 bit, unless you have a very good reason to ruin your machine by installing 64 bit.

The only reason to use Office 64 bit is if you're working with HUGE documents (usually excel or access) which are to big to load in the 32 bit version.

Otherwise you should always use 32 bit as there are several pieces of functionality which isn't implemented in the 64 bit version, especially around the browser plugins which SharePoint (prior to 2013) takes advantage of.

Due to use of shared DLLs you can't mix 32 bit and 64 bit Office on a machine. so my suggestion is that if you have the needs for 64 bit for some files then you should install it on dedicated machine (can be VM) but otherwise always use 32 bit.